# Test failures after upgrading Next from 12 to 13/ or 14

Tags: testing, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am upgrading a Next application in accordance with some library vulnerabilities and failing at the first hurdle! I am currently on 12.2.0. When I try and upgrade to 13+ I get a LOT of test suite failures and I can't for the life of me figure out why. I have upgraded all related packages as listed on the Next docs but I still get them/

I get errors such as the following:

[image]

Here is the example test suite

```
import { Action, AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { runSaga, Saga } from 'redux-saga';
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as membershipsService from '../../services/membershipsService';
import { cancelAllMembershipsSuccess, getMembershipsRequested } from '../../slices/memberships/membershipsSlice.store';
import { cancelAllMembershipsHandler, cancelAllMembershipsSaga } from './cancel-all-memberships.saga';

jest.mock('next/router', () => require('next-router-mock'));

describe('cancelAllMembershipsSaga', () => {
  let cancelAllMembershipsMock: jest.SpyInstance;
  const cancelAllMembershipsSagaGenObject = cancelAllMembershipsSaga();

  beforeEach(() => {
    cancelAllMembershipsMock = jest.spyOn(membershipsService, 'cancelAllMemberships').mockImplementation(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        status: 200,
        statusText: 'test',
        headers: {},
        config: {},
        data: { success: true },
      }),
    );
  });

  test('should wait for every memberships/cancelAllMembershipsRequested action and call cancelAllMemberships', () => {
    expect(cancelAllMembershipsSagaGenObject.next().value).toEqual(
      takeLatest('memberships/cancelAllMembershipsRequested', cancelAllMembershipsHandler),
    );
  });

  test('should be done on next iteration', () => {
    expect(cancelAllMembershipsSagaGenObject.next().done).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('should call cancelAllMemberships api and dispatch success action', async () => {
    const dispatched: AnyAction[] = [];
    await runSaga(
      {
        dispatch: (action) => dispatched.push(action as Action),
      },
      cancelAllMembershipsHandler as Saga,
    );

    expect(dispatched).toEqual([cancelAllMembershipsSuccess(), getMembershipsRequested(true)]);

    expect(cancelAllMembershipsMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cancelAllMembershipsMock.mockClear();
  });
});
```

And here are my deps:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/react-collapse": "^5.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "date-fns-tz": "^2.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "html-entities": "^2.3.3",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "^13.5.6",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^7.0.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-cache-buster": "^0.1.7",
    "react-collapse": "^5.1.1",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react-currency-format": "^1.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-password-checklist": "^1.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.3.0",
    "uuid-random": "^1.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.3.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.4",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/node": "18.0.1",
    "@types/react": "18.0.14",
    "@types/react-currency-format": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.33.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.21.2",
    "eslint": "8.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.5.6",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.2",
    "jest-next-dynamic": "^1.0.1",
    "next-router-mock": "^0.7.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.4",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
```

I am thinking it's going to be an associated library that needs upgrading or something like that but I have been unable to pin this down as of yet.
Could anyone offer any insight or advice here?

Thanks